# How to check if a web3 wallet is unlocked?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ethereum, web3js, metamask

How do I check to see if metamask or other web3 wallets are unlocked with **ethers.js**?

I currently use this:

```
window.ethereum._metamask.isUnlocked()
```

But it is reported as experimental methods by the metamask documentation.

Answer (score 2):

What my experimentation found was that [`listAccounts` returns an array of strings](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/blob/master/packages/providers/src.ts/json-rpc-provider.ts#L416) and if the wallet is not unlocked, it returns an empty array.

For MetaMask specifically, I know you can't have an account without having an address.

Therefore the function I came up with was:

```
async function isUnlocked() {
    const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);

    let unlocked;

    try {
        const accounts = await provider.listAccounts();

        unlocked = accounts.length > 0;
    } catch (e) {
        unlocked = false;
    }

    return unlocked;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's my own resolution if anyone need it :

```
isUnlocked$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

async isWalletUnlocked() {
      const web3Provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum, 'any');
      const signer = await this.web3Provider.getSigner();
    
      signer
      .getAddress()
      .then((address: string) => {
        this.isUnlocked$.next(true);
      })
      .catch((err) => this.isUnlocked$.next(false));
}
```